# MVC3 jQuery keyup event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, keyup

I have a C#.NET MVC3 web app and I want to trap the key up event on the document.  Namely, I want to know if the usre has selected "CTL->Z" to undo their data changes on the web View.  How might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var ctrlDown = false;
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 17)
        ctrlDown = true;
    if (e.which == 90)
        if (ctrlDown)
            console.log("control Z"); 
});
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 17)
        ctrlDown = false;
});
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure if e.ctrlKey from mesiesta's answer is supported cross-browser, but if it is, you could do more simply:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 90 && e.ctrlKey)
        console.log("control Z");
});
```

Comment: @Adam...great stuff.  Thanks....next wuestion I will post is....How to restore the View fields to their previous values.  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeTWebb - hmmm, well, you can attach arbitrary data to a dom element with `$("#someInput").data("previousValue", $("#someInput").val());`  You could use something like that to attach a current value at some point, that you could revert back to later:  `$("#someInput").val($("#someInput").data("previousValue"));`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this `Ctrl + Key Combination – Simple Jquery Plugin` . I've never tried to use it, but it seems a good solution for that)))

Here is the link

http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/16/ctrl-key-combination-simple-jquery-plugin/

So here is that function code

```
$.ctrl = function(key, callback, args) {
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(!args) args=[]; // IE barks when args is null
    if(e.keyCode == key.charCodeAt(0) && e.ctrlKey) {
        callback.apply(this, args);
        return false;
    }
});
};
```

And then in your code you must write only

```
$.ctrl('Z', function() {
    //What you want to do
});
```

Comment: @Mesiesta....that sweet!  Can you explain a little bit how the function code works.  I don't understand thae last if(e.ctrlKey) isCtrl = false;  or the callback.apply(this, args);

Comment: @MikeTWebb, I've missed new updated version of function, so I've edited my answer. Check that.

callback.apply call your function(in given example I function doesn't get any arguments, so args is empty).