# MVC3 jQuery..UNDO functionality

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, undo

I have a C# .NET web app and would like to implement an UNDO feature in each of the Views.  The below url is what I am doing to trap the "CTL->Z" key combination.  [MVC3 jQuery keyup event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391266/mvc3-jquery-keyup-event) Any ideas how to restore the values of each of the fields on the View after a "CTL->Z" combo is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the previous values in in a custom attribute.

```
$(control).attr("data-undo", $(control).val());
```

If you need it, just write it back to the input.

```
$(control).val($(control).attr("data-undo"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can clone your objects with jQuery clone 
http://api.jquery.com/clone/
and then look them up in clone object and move them back. You may want to take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Undo as well